# Entity Framework filter on inner list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework and have this entity mapping:

```
Parent
- Child 1 (ActiveInd = "Y")
- Child 2 (ActiveInd = "N")
- Child 3 (ActiveInd = "Y")
```

I want a Linq query similar to this (but one that will work :)

```
Parent parent = (from p in DataContext.Current.Parents 
where p.ParentId == _parentId 
&& p.Children.Active == true select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

It should return the following (only the active records):

```
Parent
- Child 1 (ActiveInd = "Y")
- Child 3 (ActiveInd = "Y")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want parents with at least one active child:

```
from p in DataContext.Current.Parents
where p.ParentId == _parentId && p.Children.Any(c => c.Active)
select p
```

If you want parents with all active children:

```
from p in DataContext.Current.Parents
where p.ParentId == _parentId && p.Children.All(c => c.Active)
select p
```

If you wanted to filter the children as part of the same query you could do something like:

```
from p in DataContext.Current.Parents
where p.ParentId == _parentId 
select new { Parent = p, ActiveChildren = p.Children.Where(c => c.Active) } into parentWithActiveChildren
where parentWithActiveChildren.FilteredChildren.Any()
select parentWithActiveChildren
```

Or

```
from p in DataContext.Current.Parents
where p.ParentId == _parentId && p.Children.Any(c => c.Active)
select new { Parent = p, ActiveChildren = p.Children.Where(c => c.Active) }
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, I will try that quickly. Will this also filter the inner list to only contain the Active records? (if not is there a way to do it?)

Comment: No and not easily, you'd have to do that as a separate operation or select into a custom object.